# I'm getting an ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: range out of bounds for buffer error

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm getting an out of bounds error when drawing a basic element with some seemingly innocuous data. I have (apologising up front for the size):

```
const vertexColourData = [

    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,

    0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,

    1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,

    0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,

    1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0/*,


    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,

    0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,

    1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,

    0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,

    1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0*/

  ],
  vertexPositionData = [

    -1.0, -1.0, +1.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, +1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, +1.0,
    -1.0, +1.0, +1.0,

    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, +1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

    -1.0, +1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, +1.0, +1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, +1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, -1.0,

    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, +1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, +1.0,

    +1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, +1.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, +1.0,

    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, +1.0,
    -1.0, +1.0, +1.0,
    -1.0, +1.0, -1.0/*,


    -1.0, -1.0, +1.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, +1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, +1.0,
    -1.0, +1.0, +1.0,

    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, +1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

    -1.0, +1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, +1.0, +1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, +1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, -1.0,

    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, +1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, +1.0,

    +1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, -1.0,
    +1.0, +1.0, +1.0,
    +1.0, -1.0, +1.0,

    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, +1.0,
    -1.0, +1.0, +1.0,
    -1.0, +1.0, -1.0*/

  ],
  vertexNormalData = [

    0.0,  0.0, +1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, +1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, +1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, +1.0,

    0.0,  0.0, -1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, -1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, -1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, -1.0,

    0.0, +1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, +1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, +1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, +1.0,  0.0,

    0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, -1.0,  0.0,

    +1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    +1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    +1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    +1.0,  0.0,  0.0,

    -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    -1.0,  0.0,  0.0/*,


    0.0,  0.0, +1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, +1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, +1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, +1.0,

    0.0,  0.0, -1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, -1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, -1.0,
    0.0,  0.0, -1.0,

    0.0, +1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, +1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, +1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, +1.0,  0.0,

    0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
    0.0, -1.0,  0.0,

    +1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    +1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    +1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    +1.0,  0.0,  0.0,

    -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
    -1.0,  0.0,  0.0*/

  ],
  vertexIndexData = [

    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    4, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 10,
    8, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14,
    12, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18,
    16, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22,
    20, 22, 23/*,

    24, 25, 26,
    24, 26, 27,
    28, 29, 30,
    28, 30, 31,
    32, 33, 34,
    32, 34, 35,
    36, 37, 38,
    36, 38, 39,
    40, 41, 42,
    40, 42, 43,
    44, 45, 46,
    44, 46, 47*/

  ];
```

When I uncomment all but the last array, all works fine. In this case, there is twice as much colour, normal and position data and the second half of it remains unused.

When I uncomment the last half of the `vertexIndexData` array, however, effectively bringing into play the last vertices, I get the following error:

> ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : `glDrawElements`: range out of bounds for buffer

I can't see where my maths is wrong. Does anyone have any ideas?

**Update:** It's nothing to do with the actual values of the vertex index data. If I try the following...

```
  vertexIndexData = [

    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    4, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 10,
    8, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14,
    12, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18,
    16, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22,
    20, 22, 23,

    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    4, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 10,
    8, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14,
    12, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18,
    16, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22,
    20, 22, 23/*,

    24, 25, 26,
    24, 26, 27,
    28, 29, 30,
    28, 30, 31,
    32, 33, 34,
    32, 34, 35,
    36, 37, 38,
    36, 38, 39,
    40, 41, 42,
    40, 42, 43,
    44, 45, 46,
    44, 46, 47*/

  ];
```

...which I thought would just draw the same triangles again, I get the same error. So it seems to me the complaint is with the size of the vertex index data's buffer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is common cause of range out of bounds of buffer in WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447641/what-is-common-cause-of-range-out-of-bounds-of-buffer-in-webgl)

Comment: Hi. Yes, I've had a look at the answer but it doesn't seem to help me. The data above doesn't seem to fall into any of the three categories explained there.

Comment: Something suprises me at first look: You have only 6 vertices, but your `vertexIndexData` contains indices fare beyond, up to 23... This is obviously "out of bound", is there something i missed ?

Comment: It's buried in the source code. I'm not sure it would help to bring it out. Also, I think I've found the problem, which seems to be down to not binding the buffer when I should. When I've found it, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the data, but the use of it. In short, I was binding the element buffers that held the vertex index information only once and not every time my `render()` method was being called. Since there are two shaders, one for colour and one for texture, the element buffer of the texture shader was the only one that was being used, since it was the one that was bound the last. Quite how it all still worked is not worth the time to find out, I'm guessing the attribute offsets and the like were identical for the two shaders. This explains why I could choose just about any values for the vertex indices and everything would still appear to work.